# confluentinc/cp-kafka - No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, sasl-scram

I'm trying to setup Kafka using the [Confluent Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/) with [SASL/SCRAM](https://kafka.apache.org/34/documentation.html#zk_authz_new_sasl). I mainly followed the [kafka-docker-playground repo section for SCRAM](https://github.com/vdesabou/kafka-docker-playground/blob/master/environment/sasl-scram/docker-compose.yml).

Here's my config:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
---
version: '3.5'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"
    volumes:
      - /zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf
          -Dzookeeper.authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
          -Dzookeeper.allowSaslFailedClients=false
          -Dzookeeper.requireClientAuthScheme=sasl"
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
      - "10000:10000"
    volumes:
      - /kafka_broker.sasl.jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_broker.sasl.jaas.conf
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 10000
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SASL_PLAINTEXT://broker:9092
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: SCRAM-SHA-256
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SCRAM-SHA-256
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_broker.sasl.jaas.conf"
```

*zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf*

```
Server {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   user_zkadmin="zkadminpwd";
};
```

*kafka_broker.sasl.jaas.conf*

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="client"
   password="clientpwd"
   user_client="clientpwd";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="zkadmin"
   password="zkadminpwd";
};
```

**Complete logs of the broker service when running `docker compose up -d`**

```
2023-07-05 11:38:21 ===> User
2023-07-05 11:38:21 uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
2023-07-05 11:38:21 ===> Configuring ...
2023-07-05 11:38:22 SASL is enabled.
2023-07-05 11:38:23 ===> Running preflight checks ... 
2023-07-05 11:38:23 ===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
2023-07-05 11:38:23 ===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,910] INFO SASL is enabled. java.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_broker.sasl.jaas.conf (io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.3--6401e4ad2087061bc6b9f80dec2d69f2e3c8660a, built on 04/08/2021 16:35 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:host.name=broker (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.16.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu11-ca (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-clients-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-4.1.12.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/minimal-json-0.9.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-metrics-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-library-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/gson-2.9.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/re2j-1.6.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-jvm-1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/disk-usage-agent-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/common-utils-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-core-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka_2.13-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-java8-compat_2.13-1.0.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-server-common-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-databind-2.13.2.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-raft-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-reflect-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-annotations-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jose4j-0.7.9.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.6.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-api-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/reload4j-1.2.19.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/utility-belt-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-metadata-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,921] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:user.name=appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=236MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=3966MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,922] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=248MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,924] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@797badd3 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,926] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,932] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 1048575 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,936] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,962] WARN SASL configuration failed. Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/etc/kafka/kafka_broker.sasl.jaas.conf'.
2023-07-05 11:38:23 at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.<init>(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:189)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1161)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1210)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,966] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.23.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,970] ERROR Error occurred while connecting to Zookeeper server[zookeeper:2181]. Authentication failed.  (io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus)
2023-07-05 11:38:23 [2023-07-05 09:38:23,974] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.23.0.3:59042, server: zookeeper/172.23.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 [2023-07-05 09:38:24,012] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper/172.23.0.2:2181, session id = 0x10000a90a110000, negotiated timeout = 40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 [2023-07-05 09:38:24,018] WARN An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x10000a90a110000. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x10000a90a110000, likely server has closed socket
2023-07-05 11:38:24 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 [2023-07-05 09:38:24,121] INFO Session: 0x10000a90a110000 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 [2023-07-05 09:38:24,121] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000a90a110000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-07-05 11:38:24 Using log4j config /etc/kafka/log4j.properties
```

Main error is: `javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/etc/kafka/kafka_broker.sasl.jaas.conf'.`

The thing is that the JAAS config file for ZooKeeper is working, but not the one for the broker, even if they both have similar "volumes" properties, usage and JAAS format. Can anyone help me with that?

**UPDATE 1**:

I changed paths to a relative format surrounded by quotes:

```
volumes:
      - "./zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf"
```

Now, the error is located in ZooKeeper, but the JAAS file is effectively present in the container (see my answers below this post).

**Logs of the zookeeper service**:

```
2023-07-06 10:00:14 [2023-07-06 08:00:14,477] ERROR No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was found in '/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf'. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
2023-07-06 10:00:14 [2023-07-06 08:00:14,477] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
2023-07-06 10:00:14 java.io.IOException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was found in '/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf'.
2023-07-06 10:00:14     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory.configureSaslLogin(ServerCnxnFactory.java:265)
2023-07-06 10:00:14     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:637)
2023-07-06 10:00:14     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:158)
2023-07-06 10:00:14     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:112)
2023-07-06 10:00:14     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:67)
2023-07-06 10:00:14     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:140)
2023-07-06 10:00:14     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:90)
```

Comment: Where are your JAAS files actually ocated? You're trying to mount them from the root of your host fs... Can you exec into the container and cat the file contents?

Comment: Hi! All files are located in the project's root directory (thus they are imported from the relative "/" path). I updated path to be sure to use them correctly:
`volumes:
      - "./zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf"`

Comment: Also, I added a command property to both ZooKeeper and Kafka services: `tail -f /dev/null`, maintaining the containers alive.
And I can cat both files from the two services:
`cat /etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf ` returns `Server {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   user_zkadmin="zkadminpwd";
};`.

Comment: Now, the error is located in the ZooKeeper JAAS config (see my updated answer).

Comment: Before changing paths, `/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf` was an empty directory in the container. But why is it working on the [playground example](https://github.com/vdesabou/kafka-docker-playground/blob/master/environment/sasl-scram/docker-compose.yml) then?

Comment: You don't need tail command. I assume you mean file, not directory? Also, /etc/kafka isn't actually used by the confluent containers... The repo works because it's using files in a **relative** parent folder of the repo, not files at the root directory of your OS

Comment: @OneCricketeer So, tail command was added to keep the container alive, because when the broker starts, it immediatly shut down if it can't connect to ZooKeeper (connect to the ZooKeeper IP and then authenticate if this is indicated in its properties). Because something goes wrong, the broker cannot authenticate, leading to immediate shutdown of the container. Tail command is only here to access the container's data (docker exec like commands) while container is alive, because otherwise, you cannot browser container's file.

Comment: No that's correct, because I wasn't using relative path imports ("/" instead of "./"), these paths were considered as directories, not files, leading to the first discovered error. I now assume that the `No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file` error was throwed because the broker could not read the JAAS file. Now, files are effectively accessible from the container, but the error is `No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was found in '/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf'.`.

Comment: So yes, my mistake on that one, but I still cannot get it to work :(

Comment: TLDR:  the tail  command is only added when we want to browse container's files, otherwise it is removed. Before fixing paths, directories were imported to the container, not files, so that JAAS configuration of ZooKeeper and broker necessarily fail.

Comment: *Also, /etc/kafka isn't actually used by the confluent containers...*

What do you mean by that?
Here's snippets of the docker-compose.yml of the playground:
`volumes:
        - ../../environment/sasl-scram/zookeeper/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.config:/etc/kafka/zookeeper_server_jaas.conf`

And they use /etc/kafka path inside the container:
`KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"`

Or do you mean that I could pass directly JAAS config as inline properties? I could, but I prefer to keep them separate in files because it would be shared with others.

Comment: Also, I didn't explain well the absolute paths issue: absolute paths I was using didn't exist, but Docker still creates it even if directory/file path don't exists. You can see that behavior by replacing the volume in ZooKeeper service by:
`volumes:
      - "/thisfolderdoesnotexist:/etc/kafka/zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf"`
This does not throw any error in the ZooKeeper container, and if you browse the container's files, you can see that thisfolderdoesnotexist is a folder. So, files didn't exists at the specified path, so Docker assumed they were directories, leading to the first error.

Comment: * *zookeeper.sasl.jaas.conf* is a folder (from the previous comment)
Sorry for the many mistakes!

Comment: You need to mount a single conf file, though, not a whole folder.

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, that's exactly what I described in my previous answsers: ancien paths = folder, new paths = files. Unfortunately, it's not working even with files.

Comment: Well, I ended up getting it working with Kraft. I will try to check this issue again in a near time and update the post if someone gets that same issue. Thanks for your time!